# Xcode 8 beta 3 build error with framework(lipo: -remove i386 specified but fat file does not contain that architecture)

Tags: xcode, carthage

I'm running into an issue I can't figure out with Xcode 8 beta 2. I have a library I'm including as a framework built through Carthage. I'm able to build once, but all following builds fail with the following error:

```
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: -remove i386 specified but fat file: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-dftppwvljrlqmlgzlpklqyuamtkp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/KGNCache.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/KGNCache does not contain that architecture
```

If I clean I'm able to build, but the next build will fail with the same error.